# We are looking for a function $f(x)$ that satisfies the functional equation of both $f(1)=1$ and $f(x+1)=xf(x)$.

Tags: calculus

We have the functional equation of both $f(1)=1$ and $f(x+1)=xf(x)$, where $x$ is a real number.
We need to show that this equation has an infinite number of solutions $f(x)$.
I have received a hint that it is sufficient to show that the functions $f(x)=\cos(2\pi m x) * \Gamma(x)$ are solutions, where $m$ is a natural number and $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.

I know that $\cos(2\pi m x)$ always stays between $-1$ and $1$, but otherwise I have no idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have all; use

$$\cos(2\pi m(x+1))=\cos(2\pi mx+2\pi m)=...$$

and

$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x) $$

to prove $f(x+1)=xf(x)$. 
The equality $f(1)=1$ follows from $\cos(2\pi m)=...$, and $\Gamma(1)=0!=...$.